# communication between static method and instance field in java

Tags: java, oop, static

"Static methods may not communicate with instance fields, only static fields". I got to read this quoted lines. When I studied other threads in this forum, I found that we can use instance fields in static methods and vice versa. So, what does this quote means?? Is it true?

Comment: Please post your code. We can likley help you do what your trying to do a different way.

Comment: Sorry, I am just studying some material.

Comment: Gottcha. Well Bozho's explination is quite good. you should check it out.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't use non-static (instance) fields in static method. That's because a static method is not associated with an instance.

A `static` method is one-per-class, while a class may have many instances. So if you have 2 instances, the fields of which one will the static methods see?

Let's imagine that this is valid:

```
class Foo {
   private int bar;

   public static int getBar() {
      return bar; // does not compile;
   }
}
```

And then:

```
Foo foo1 = new Foo();
foo1.bar = 1;
Foo foo2 = new Foo();
foo2.bar = 2;

Foo.getBar(); // what would this return. 1 or 2?
```

Answer (score 2):

```
class MyClass{
  int i ;
  static String res;
  public static void myMethod(){
      i = 10 //not allowed because it is instance non static field
      res = "hello" ; allowed , because it is static field
      new MyClass().i = 10;//allowed as we are accessing it using an instance of that class
  }


}
```

**Description**: Static fields/methods/.. are associated with class not with object of that class. where member variable/methods are associated with class's object so to access them we need object of class

**Also See**

- [Documentation](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html)

Comment: but what does the line `new MyClass().i = 10` do? Unless he stores the object somewhere it doesnt do him any good.

Comment: @kralco626 I hope you got your answer

Comment: but what does the line `new MyClass().i = 10` do? Unless he stores the object somewhere it doesnt do him any good. - alright a downvote is a bit harsh. But your not explaing in your code why you can't do what he is trying to do. and I have coded a lot of java... can't see the reason to create a instance, assign a value to one of its variables, but then not store it... He is clearly new at oop, he needs a clear, simple, concreate example.

Comment: @kralco626 I hope now it answers your question well, and  I have never told that `new MyClass().i = 10;` is useful just demonstrating the cases

Comment: @org.life.java - i'm just saying, he's clearly new to oop, so he would benifit from seeing that stored as a variable. If your going to create you mine as well store it. But we seem to have beat the point to death :) and I don't think he is following the question anymore :)

Comment: @kralco626 ah yes, I think the given info is enough to make him/her understand the point, point me out if something is missing , I mean for very new bie to oop

Answer (score 1):

You can't use instance fields in a static method. Which instance are you referring to ?

However a static method *may* have a reference to an instance, and thus use the fields on that instance.

e.g.

```
public class Stock {
  public double price = 0.0;

  public static void setPriceIncorrectly() {
     price = 0.0 // which price ?
  }

  public static void setPriceCorrectly() {
     Stock s = new Stock();
     s.price = 0.0 // which price ?
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> I found that we can use instance
>   fields in static methods and vice
>   versa

That isn't true; you can't refer to instance fields in "static" methods because "static" methods don't belong to an "instance".

Recommended reading: http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html

Answer (score 0):

You can't use something that do not exists.

When You have static field or method is not associated with an instace. so the non static elements does not exists.

Answer (score 0):

You always need an instance to communicate with instance fields. If you have access to an instance (e.g. param or static field) you can access their members. But you cannot access instance fields of the class directly.